# Quarkus Cassandra Integration

Tags: cassandra, quarkus

Quarkus suppot many database, SQL and NoSQL.
Cassandra have best performance on benchemark, much better when using "ScyllaDB", database based on Cassandra.
When will we have integration with Cassandra? I don´t have any information about. If need help, I would be proud to help.

Comment: There are some issues: 
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2681 
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2682 https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7876

Answer (score 1):

There is a team at DataStax working on a Quarkus extension for Cassandra. If you are looking for something to get your hands on, see the GitHub repo below.

https://github.com/datastax/cassandra-quarkus